# Is there a chance that my real IP can be traced if I surf through a VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip, website

Is there a chance that my real IP can be traced if I surf through a VPN?

Which IP is registered to any particular website I visit?  What if I disconnect the VPN after browsing, can my real IP be still traced from the VPN I used?

I have searched for this on the web but found nothing.  Appreciate all your suggestions and answers.

Comment: There is no 100% anonymity on the web. You can layer up measures to improve your anonymity but it is like with encryption. Any encryption code is breakable it is just a matter of time and resources. That being said if the VPN connection is setup properly, then the web will see your VPN provider IP address when you browse. Also log retention policy at your provider is important. Many of them delete the logs linking your IP address to their IP address within hours (or at least they claim they do).

Answer (score 2):

Your 'IP address' is just one piece of the traces you leave behind when you communicate with another involved party:

- You do not know what the VPN-provider does once your session is over. Does it log your IP? Has someone else hacked the VPN-provider? If someone has the authority to he might just trace your communication back to the VPN-provider, then go to the provider with a piece of legal voodoo or with some bullies and force him to hand over your 'real' 'IP address'.
- If you do not communicate over encrypted channels (https, etc) to the endpoint, all the other stuff like your username or your login-email etc are all transmitted in plain-text. Have you control over all involved stations between your VPN-provider and the endpoint? Unlikely.
- Have you control over the endpoint and what they might do with the information they have about you? Unlikely.
- Somewhere in between the the VPN-provider and your endpoint might inject some malicious code into your session while you are surfing the web. Then this piece of code runs on YOUR machine and it might just disclose any information it can collect, your 'real IP' is only one tiny piece of that.
- You don't need the IP address of someone to detect with a very high rate of accuracy that it's the same person, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_targeting

etc etc. You can use Tor to blur your identity ... but if someone want's to trace you he is able to do so. The more money is involved, the more likely this is.

'Anonymity' is not the feature you get out of using a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Websites will see the address of the VPN provider, and know you are emerging from said VPN provider.

Your ISP will see encrypted traffic to VPN provider, but they **can't see what you are doing with it.**

Some VPNs claim not to keep logs, **but** those that do can access your logs if they found you doing some unethical activities on the web, usually with a subpoena by police etc. But they usually don't look into users data by themselves, because their data base is big, and how can they check every single persons activity-not worth the manpower and resources.

VPN **will** mask your original IP, and with that no one can identify where you actually coming from. But you need to make sure that the IP you are using has strong protocols. If you are using **dynamic IP** then every session will give you new IP, so the chance are rare that someone can find out who you are, and what you are doing.

However, there are rumours that the [NSA can penetrate VPNs](http://www.darkreading.com/risk-management/nsa-surveillance-can-penetrate-vpns/d/d-id/1110996?), but keep in mind that this is just a rumour.